# Make SKSpriteNode move towards point

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using the following code to make a physicsbody attached to a spritenode move towards a point (pt).

The problem is that I have obstacles (ie a circle) that block the path of the dots to the point and they have to continuously "push" against the obstacle until they move past it (this will always work in physics unless they are perfectly perpendicular to the obstacle's tangent) and they way I am doing it works, but it makes really small "bounces" off of the obstacle even though I have the restitution set to 0 on both bodies.

How can I fix this?

```
double velocity_multiplier = 3*obstacle_move_speed;
if(page == 2){
    velocity_multiplier = 2;
    pt = CGPointMake(0, 160);
}

double dx = pt.x - dot.position.x;
double dy = pt.y - dot.position.y;

double dot_distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

if(dot_distance < distance){
    distance = dot_distance;
}

if(dot_distance < 50){
    velocity_multiplier = 1;
}

dot.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx * velocity_multiplier, dy * velocity_multiplier);
```

Comment: Why a tag for Sprite Kit and Cocos?

Comment: Because they use similar physics engines

Comment: Try setting the friction to zero as well. Friction is called different things in box2d, chipmunk and spritekit I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't have any effect. They still bounce sporadically off of each other and obstacles when at a high velocity

Comment: @TheisEgeberg Any other ideas?

Comment: 1. Could you make a video of the "Sporadic bouncing"?

2. If not. I'd suggest that you start to track the collisions, and then pause the game when a collision hits. Then add a little button to your game which starts the game again. Just so you can visually get some ideas of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try thhis

```
[ball runAction:[SKAction moveTo:point duration:0.3]];
```